# Text alignment in Android Popup Menus

Tags: android, popup

What does the text alignment inside the items of a `PopupMenu` depend on? 
I create Popup menus by clicking on ImageButtons in different parts of my app, and I noticed that sometimes the text alignment of the items is centered, sometimes it is aligned to the left or to the right. I didn't set any style explitly, so is there a general rule for that?

Here is a screenshot of a PopupMenu. The first item is aligned right, the second seems centered but who knows. I'm using Lollipop, and actually a couple of days ago before the OS update the same PopupMenu had all items aligned left (as I want them).

[image: my image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of text in a PopupMenu being centered and include OS version information? That shouldn't happen unless you've poked the popup menu style.

Comment: I added a screenshot. I did not set any style for Popup menus.

Comment: It looks like this is probably a framework bug. Would you mind filing an issue at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list and including that screenshot?